# Como converter uma string para um número em Lua?

Tags: string, lua, conversão-de-tipo

Em Lua, como converter um valor do tipo string para o tipo número (inteiro, float etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Lua realiza uma **[conversão automática](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/pt/manual.html#3.4.2)** entre os tipos `string` e `number` e vice-versa em tempo de execução.

```
> print(1+"20")
21
> print(1 .. "2")
12
```

Caso você queira converter **explicitamente** um `number` para uma `string`, utilize a função [`tonumber`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/pt/manual.html#pdf-tonumber).

```
> local a = tonumber("999")
999

> local phi = tonumber("1.61803")
1.61803

> print(tonumber("100e20"))
1e+22
```

Além disso, é `tonumber` aceita uma **base**, que pode variar entre 2 e 36, como segundo argumento.

```
> print(tonumber("A",16))
10

> print(tonumber("101010",2))
42
```

Comment: O último exemplo não funciona em Lua 5.3. Funcionava por acaso nas versões anteriores. `tonumber("101010",2)` funciona em todas as versões. Quer dizer, se vai dar uma base, use um string.

Comment: @lhf corrigido!